# Handling invalid viewstate error

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7

We had some security/penetration testers test our ASP.NET application, and they identified something thought to be a cross-site scripting vulnerability.  From what I can tell, it looks like they manually manipulated the viewstate of a postback by inserting the text `<ScRiPt>alert(1)</ScRiPt>` into one of the viewstate parameters.  For some reason, even though we have custom error handlers specified in the web.config, the server seems to ignore them and just spits back a generic error message with the viewstate displayed verbatim.  As a result, the `<ScRiPt>alert(1)</ScRiPt>` runs in the browser causing the testers to identify this as a cross-site scripting problem.  Whether or not this is a legitimate vulnerability, I'd like to be able to properly handle this error and redirect it to one of our custom error pages, or at the very least prevent the server from just spitting back the viewstate as is in the error message.

In addition to looking into the .NET Error Pages and Error Pages for the website in IIS, I have also tried doing something in the Application_Error method of the global.asax.  There I can see that the status code is 500 and the WebEventCode is System.Web.Management.WebEventCodes.RuntimeErrorViewStateFailure, but I can't do a Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer there because I get a "Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback." exception.  I've also tried setting EnableViewStateMac to true and ViewStateEncryptionMode to Always in the web.config to see if that would change things, but I was still able to recreate the issue.  I'd appreciate any insight someone out there might have.

The error response I'm getting back from the server looks like this:

```
0|/*DX*/({'generalError':'Invalid viewstate. \r\n\tClient IP: 127.0.0.1\r\n\tPort: 51510\r\n\tReferer: https://localhost/-mysettings.aspx\r\n\tPath: /Default.aspx\r\n\tUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1\r\n\tViewState: /wEPDwUKMjA1OTAyNzk1MWQYBAUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFjQFQmN0bDAxJG1haW5Db250ZW50JGN0bDAwJGNwQWRtaW5pc3RyYXRpb25TZXR0aW5ncyRidG5DaGFuZ2VQYXNzd29yZAU/Y3RsMDEkbWFpbkNvbnRlbnQkY3RsMDAkY3BBZG1pbmlzdHJhdGlvblNldHRpbmdzJGJ0bkVkaXRQaWN0dXJlBT9jdGwwMSRtYWluQ29udGVudCRjdGwwMCRjcEFkbWluaXN0cmF0aW9uU2V0dGluZ3MkYnRuU2F2ZUNoYW5nZXMFQmN0bDAxJG1haW5Db250ZW50JGN0bDAwJGNwQWRtaW5pc3RyYXRpb<ScRiPt>alert(1)</ScRiPt>25TZXR0aW5ncyRjYlNpdGVDb3VudHJ5JERERAU8Y3RsMDEkbWFpbkNvbnRlbnQkY3RsMDAkY3BBZG1pbmlzdHJhdGlvblNldHRpbmdzJEFTUHhCdXR0b24zBV9jdGwwMSRtYWluQ29udGVudCRjdGwwMCRjcEFkbWluaXN0cmF0aW9uU2V0dGluZ3MkdXNlckFkZHJlc3MkcG5sQWRkcmVzcyRjYlNlYXJjaGFibGVBZGRyZXNzJERERAU8Y3RsMDEkbWFpbkNvbnRlbnQkY3RsMDAkY3BBZG1pbmlzdHJhdGlvblNldHRpbmdzJEFTUHhCdXR0b24yBT9jdGwwMSRtYWluQ29udGVudCRjdGwwMCRjcEFkbWluaXN0cmF0aW9uU2V0dGluZ3Mk...'})
```

Comment: For the amount that security/penetration testers charge IME, did they not suggest a way to avoid that? If you get the error in real life, then it's a MITM attack, or the end-user's computer is already infected with malware, or it's someone deliberately messing around with the viewstate. Whichever of those it is, your website has correctly refused to process the request and the bad data will be propagated no further. I had one penetration test report saying that ".aspx" on the end of a URL was a vulnerability as it indicated that IIS was being used.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to come up with a workable solution.  It's not perfect but gets the job done and prevents the javascript from appearing in the server response.  I basically just clear the current error and output my own custom response.  I put the following code in the Application_Error method of the Global.asax:

```
//Handle view state manipulation
HttpApplication httpApp = this.Context.ApplicationInstance;
HttpException httpEx = httpApp.Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
if (httpEx != null)
{
    if (
        httpEx.WebEventCode == System.Web.Management.WebEventCodes.AuditInvalidViewStateFailure
        ||
        httpEx.WebEventCode == System.Web.Management.WebEventCodes.InvalidViewState
        ||
        httpEx.WebEventCode == System.Web.Management.WebEventCodes.InvalidViewStateMac
        ||
        httpEx.WebEventCode == System.Web.Management.WebEventCodes.RuntimeErrorViewStateFailure
        )
    {
        HttpContext.Current.ClearError();
        Response.Write("Error: An invalid viewstate has been detected (WebEventCode: " + httpEx.WebEventCode.ToString() + ").");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They manipulated the page source to add a script code that is then executed. That is not a vulnerability by any book (since the value was not persisted and the alert executed only as a direct result of their action - it's like they are hacking themselves). There was nothing stopping them from adding that script directly in the page...

As for the error message, you should look into setting `<customErrors mode="On" />` in your web.config file. [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If that does not help, another option would be to clear the exception in `Application_Error` and throwing a generic exception.

Comment: I have already tried <customErrors mode="On" />, and it works for most things, but for some reason this specific error bypasses it or never gets to it.  Just now, I also tried throwing generic exceptions and a new HttpException in Application_Error, but that didn't change the response.  Regarding the vulnerability, I guess it's theoretically possible someone could use this in a phishing attack.  For example, pass this type of viewstate data in via the querystring and trick people into entering data on a page from a legitimate looking URL with a valid SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem to pass the PCI test.

I think this link below addresses this issue, but I don't how to have it fixed.
http://computersecuritywithethicalhacking.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/stored-xss-via-viewstate-parameter.html

We use IIS 7.5, on our website, enableviewstate is true, enableviewstatemac is true.
But I don't how to check the viewStateEncryptionMode setting. I am not sure if the viewstate is encrypted.